# The Newton Algorithm - Proving Convexity of $x^r$ and finding the global minima

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, newton-raphson

I am working on some exercises for the Newton Algorithm and wanted to consult you all. For part c) I would like some help.

[image]

Just based on a graphical interpretation I would assume that $r$ just needs to be even because for odd $r$ the function is not convex on the entire domain, $x \in R$

Again for the global minima, I can show that the only stationary point occurs at $x=0$, and that the function is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and on $(- \infty, 0]$ Is this sufficient?

I am a bit confused how to show the last part and would appreciate some hints. The newton algorithm has the form

$x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha d_k$ where $d_k = \frac{\nabla f(x_k)}{||\nabla^2 f(x_k)||_2}$

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Thank you to the person who replied to me below. I have tried the following, compute derivative and second derivative and by analysing the second derivative, found that only for $r$ being even do we have that $f''(x) \geq 0, \forall x$.

For the stationary points I found the point where the derivative equals 0 which is $x* = 0$. Plugging this into the second derivative is useless so what I did is argue that for even $r$ we have a symmetric function whose derivative for $x>0$ is strictly increasing and so the point must be a global minima.

For part c) using the optimal $x* = 0$, the newton method became $x_k - \frac{\alpha x^k}{r-1}$ which I substituted into the inequality and got $$| $x_k - \frac{\alpha x^k}{r-1}| \geq (1-\delta)|x_k|$$ which upon rearranging I found that $\delta \geq \frac{\alpha}{r-1}$

What do you think? Is this valid/rigorous enough?

Comment: You are right to restrict yourself to even $r$. For the last part, note that if $r$ is even, the unique global minimum will be $x^{\star} = 0$ and you essentially have to show that
$|x_{k+1}| \geq (1 - \delta) |x_{k}|$. You can try showing it for $r = 2$.

Comment: Hello, what do you think of my follow up in the edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need $r$ to be be positive even number. In particular, we can choose $r$ to be $2$ if you wish.

Indeed we have

$$|x^k-\alpha \cdot  \frac{x^k}{r-1}| = |x^k| \left|1-\frac{\alpha}{r-1}\right|$$

We can pick $\delta$ to be $\frac{\alpha}{r-1}$, provided we pick $\alpha$ to be less than $r-1$.

Comment: Doesn't $\delta$ need to be $\geq \frac{\alpha}{r-1}$ for the inequality to hold?

Comment: I just need to illustrate that such $\delta$ exists, I just have to pick one of them.